# Why can't I set PID gains through JointController?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

When I set the gains of my PID object using a direct reference it works, as :

```
common::PID pid = common::PID(0.1, 0, 0);
std::cout << pid.GetPGain();

pid.SetPGain(0.5);
std::cout << pid.GetPGain();
```

produces

```
0.1
0.5
```

However, when I access it through the joint controller, the gain value isn't set.

```
std::cout << model->GetJointController()->GetPositionPIDs()[joint->GetScopedName()]->GetPGain();

model->GetJointController()->GetPositionPIDs()[joint->GetScopedName()]->SetPGain(0.5);

std::cout << model->GetJointController()->GetPositionPIDs()[joint->GetScopedName()]->GetPGain();
```

produces

```
0.1
0.1
```

Does GetPositionPIDs  not provide you with the actual PID objects, but a bunch of copies?

Cheers,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/15321/why-can%27t-i-set-pid-gains-through-jointcontroller?/) by [kaldo](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3006/kaldo/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 13 on 2017-01-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Yes, it looks like `GetPositionPIDs` is returning copies. See this at the [API](http://osrf-distributions.s3.amazonaws.com/gazebo/api/dev/classgazebo_1_1physics_1_1JointController.html#ab4d442e73e7e61890e888c41b8f86141) documentation.

I think the correct way to do what you want is to construct a new PID object and use `Joint::Controller:SetPositionPID` ([API](http://osrf-distributions.s3.amazonaws.com/gazebo/api/dev/classgazebo_1_1physics_1_1JointController.html#a28d093602e282cb03caa328396e79164))

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2017-01-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kaldo](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3006/kaldo/) on 2017-01-27**:
Actually, reading the doc had led me to think I would get the actual objects. So I was surprised at the actual behavior and wondering if it was intended.

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2017-01-27**:
I believe a copy is made unless you return a reference or a pointer.